# Customize the scroll bar on my website

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar, customization

I recently saw the new gmail look, and am liking the scroll bar when you have lots of emails. How can I replicate this in my site?

Also, how can I start from scratch, and another sub-question: can I put an image for the background of the scroll bar, e.g a PNG Background.

How can I replicate this, in any way: jquery, css etc?

Also, how can I make the scroll bar be fatter, and occupy more, or less space.

Thanks

**EDIT: Is it also possible to allow the end user to change the size, baground color etc through a simple form, if they are provided a bunch of different options / themes?**

Comment: Would you like fries with that too?

Comment: @MarcB I'm sorry, I don't know what you are getting at?

Comment: Not sure why everyone is being so negative about this post...

Comment: @JBellamy generally, SO asks that users be specific about the problem they are trying to solve. To compare questions: "I have implemented this: X but it still doesn't quite look like Y, what can I do" is a different question to "please tell me how to remake Y"? As you can see the answers are veering towards techniques for working out how, as the latter case is too wide to give a decent, complete answer for. You'll get a much better reception by trying something and asking about where you are stuck than asking us to implement an entire feature for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a similar custom scrollbar somewhere, grab a copy of the code, implements and enjoy.

[Like this](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/).

*can I put an image for the background of the scroll bar, e.g a PNG Background?*
Yes. It's CSS+JS.

*How can I replicate this, in any way: jquery, css etc?*
See link.

*Also, how can I make the scroll bar be fatter, and occupy more, or less space.*
By changing the CSS.

*Is it also possible to allow the end user to change the size, baground color etc through a simple form, if they are provided a bunch of different options / themes?*
Yes.

Comment: Just make sure you pick one that also works with the scrollwheel and arrow-keys, not just with the mouse clicking the arrows. People hate that.

Comment: I wrote a jQuery plugin recently which creates GMail like scrollbars, if you like, can check it out here: https://github.com/umarashfaq/draggy

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to see how they do that is to use firebug to see what kind of css declaration they use.

with that i can see that the scrollbar look is achieved by `-webkit-scrollbar`:

http://www.css3.info/styling-scrollbars-the-webkit-way/